# UI Grid getting blank when filtering data using external filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using UI grid v3.0.0 in my project. Recently I changed my code to filter grid using drop down list value. After this change, UI grid getting blank when I filter grid multiple times. This is intermittent issue and I am not getting any javascript error. when UI grid get blanked after applying filter, UI grid will remain blank till user move scroll bar of UI grid.

I am using below Grid options.

```js
     $scope.options = {
       enableColumnMenus: false,
    enableSelectAll: true,
       enableFiltering: true,
       enableHorizontalScrollbar:0, 
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
       enableRowSelection: true,
       data :  [], 
    showSelectionCheckbox: true,
    selectionRowHeaderWidth: 25,
    rowHeight: 25,
    columnDefs : $scope.columnDefs
    };
     
     $scope.options.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
      $scope.options = gridApi;
      gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($rootScope , function(gridApi) {
       $scope.options.selected = gridApi;
   });
```

I am also calling  below grid api for refresh after filering ui grid array .

```js
    $scope.options.core.refresh();
```

But still it is not working. If anyone can give me the hint about how this problem can be solved, it would me much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have never been able to get the core.refresh to work for me.  I actually use a workaround.  You can try it to see if it helps with this issue.

create Function:

```
 $scope.refresh = false;

  function refresh () {
    $scope.refresh = true;
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.refresh = false;
    }, 0);
};
```

Put an `ng-if` on your grid div:

```
                <div ng-if="!refresh" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

Then call `refresh()` in your controller where/when you want to refresh the grid.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for answer. I have one doubt . in refresh function, you are just setting refresh to false. what you are trying to in refresh code? how it works?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set scroll position after refresh like below :

```
$scope.options.core.refresh();    
$scope.options.core.scrollTo($scope.data[0], $scope.columnDefs[0]);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use $filter of angular to filter your kendo grid dataSource.

You can take the reference from following code, let me know anything else you required.

```
 var ds = $filter('filter')($scope.grdDataSource.dataSource.data, $scope.searchText);
 $scope.kendoGridOptions.dataSource.data = ds;
```

Comment: He is not using a kendo grid.  He is using ui-grid.